# Рандомный выбор файла для считывания

Tags: ios, swift, файлы, struct

Я пытаюсь передать рандомное значение( имя файла из enum) в параметр для метода считывания файла. Но выдает ошибку  OptinalValue:file .

Как я могу передать рандомное  название файла из структуры в параметр метода getDataFromFIle()

**ReadFile.swift**

```
import Foundation

var content:String!

class readFile
{
      //метод для читки файла
    func getDataFromFile(name: String , type:String)
    {

        let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
        //в этом рядке ошибка
        let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let  randomContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: [".","!"]).randomElement()!//.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
        content = randomContent
    }
}
```

**TaskFile.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct TaskName
{
    enum LvlOne
    {
        case taskOneLvlOne
        case taskTwoLvlOne
        case taskThreeLvlOne

        var fileNameLvlOne:String
        {
            switch self {
            case .taskOneLvlOne:
                return "taskOneLvlOne"
            case .taskTwoLvlOne:
                return "taskTwoLvlOne"
            case.taskThreeLvlOne:
                return "TaskThreeLvlOne"
            }
        }
    }
    enum LvlTwo
    {
        case taskOneLvlTwo
        case taskTwoLvlTwo
        case taskThreeLvltwo

        var fileNameLvlTwo:String
        {
            switch self {
            case .taskOneLvlTwo:
                return "taskOneLvlTwo"
            case .taskTwoLvlTwo:
                return "taskTwoLvlTwo"
            case.taskThreeLvltwo:
                return "taskThreeLvltwo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ShowContent.swift**

```
func getContent()
{
    let contentFile = readFile.init()
    conentFile.getDateFromFile(name: TaskName.LvlTwo.allCases.randomElement()!, type: "txt")
    let conentFile = content

    lebel.text = contentFile!
}
```

Comment: Пример выбора рандомного элемента в `enum` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261011/swift-chose-a-random-enumeration-value  Но у вас как я понимаю вопрос не только в этом, так что возможно его следует разбить на несколько

Comment: Я исправил свой вопрос. ПОсмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае можно сделать например так, сделав метод с дженериками

```
/// Метод для выбора случайного значения, передаем в него первое значение в enum
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261971/3004003
func randomEnumElement<T: RawRepresentable>(_ arg: T) -> T where T.RawValue==UInt32 {

    // find the maximum enum value
    var count: UInt32 = 0

    while let _ = T.init(rawValue: count) {
        count += 1
    }

    // pick and return a new value
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(count)

    return T.init(rawValue: rand)!
}
```

Тогда `enum` для его использования будет таким

```
struct TaskName
{
    enum LvlOne : UInt32
    {
        case taskOneLvlOne
        case taskTwoLvlOne
        case taskThreeLvlOne

        static var randomElement: Self {
            randomEnumElement(LvlOne.taskOneLvlOne)
        }

        static var fileNameLvlOne: String
        {
            switch randomElement {
            case .taskOneLvlOne:
                return "taskOneLvlOne"
            case .taskTwoLvlOne:
                return "taskTwoLvlOne"
            case.taskThreeLvlOne:
                return "TaskThreeLvlOne"
            }
        }

    }

    // ...
}
```

Использование

```
let fileName = TaskName.LvlOne.fileNameLvlOne
getDataFromFile(name: fileName, type: "txt")
```

Comment: Сапсибо. Очень помогли)